# Insert with Hibernate native query does not work for java.util.Date

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, spring, jpa

I am using Hibernate JPA and Spring with a Mysql database and I want to insert using a SQL statement like this:

```
Date saveDate = new Date();
java.sql.Timestamp timeStampDate = new Timestamp(saveDate.getTime());
Query persistableQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO TASK_ASSESSMENT (ACTIVE_FLAG, ASSESSMENT_DATE, DESCRIPTION, "
        + "TITLE, NEEDS_LEVEL_ID, PATIENT_ID, USER_ID) VALUES ("
        + true +", " + timeStampDate + ", " + description + ", " + title + ", "
        + needsLevelId + ", " + patientId + ", " + userId + " )");
persistableQuery.executeUpdate();
```

But after running it I get the following error:

```
WARN : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: -11, SQLState: 37000
ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Unexpected token: 15 in statement
    [INSERT INTO TASK_ASSESSMENT (ACTIVE_FLAG, ASSESSMENT_DATE, DESCRIPTION, TITLE,
    NEEDS_LEVEL_ID, PATIENT_ID, USER_ID)
    VALUES (true, 2011-03-01 15?, any description, , 193, 1, 3 )]
```

Could someone help me on this please?

PS. I am aware of using hibernate in non-native way, but I need to use native way. I am also of insert ...from... , but I don't think it will help.

Finally I think the problem is mainly with the date. How do you guys pass on MySQL a `datetime` type using Java?

**Update:**

The following works fine, I guess it is a java date to mysql datetime conversion problem.

```
("INSERT INTO TASK_ASSESSMENT "
     + "(ACTIVE_FLAG, ASSESSMENT_DATE, DESCRIPTION, TITLE, "
     + "NEEDS_LEVEL_ID, PATIENT_ID, USER_ID) "
     + "VALUES (true, 1999-12-22, '" + description + "', '" 
     + title + "', " + needsLevelId+", " + patientId 
     + ", " + userId + ")");
```

Could anyone please help me on how to convert `java.util.Date` to MySQL `datetime`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't use concatenation to insert data into queries, use parameters instead. It solves problem with wrong representation of values, as well as many other problems:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(
    "INSERT INTO TASK_ASSESSMENT (ACTIVE_FLAG, ASSESSMENT_DATE, DESCRIPTION, "
    + "TITLE, NEEDS_LEVEL_ID, PATIENT_ID, USER_ID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
    .setParameter(1, true)
    .setParameter(2, saveDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) // Since you want it to be a TIMESTAMP
    .setParameter(3, description)
    .setParameter(4, title)
    .setParameter(5, needsLevelId)
    .setParameter(6, patientId)
    .setParameter(7, userId) 
    .executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a few issues.  Some of your fields should have quotes around them.  Also, possibly you need to format the timestamp in a different way, not sure how mysql expects it?

```
Query persistableQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
    "INSERT INTO TASK_ASSESSMENT 
        (ACTIVE_FLAG, ASSESSMENT_DATE, DESCRIPTION, "
    + "TITLE, NEEDS_LEVEL_ID, PATIENT_ID, USER_ID) VALUES ("
        + true +", " 
    + "'" + timeStampDate + "'"
    + ", " 
    + "'" + description + "'"
    + ", " 
    + "'" + title + "'"
    + ", "                                                            
    + "'" + needsLevelId + "')");
```

As far as formatting the date, I suspect you will need to look at the SimpleDateFormat class, which will let you get the date into whatever format mysql expects.  See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: If you insert the variables directly into the SQL statement, the user is able to perform an sql injection attack by just adding a statement after the variable. Using parameters prevents this, looks much cleaner and you don't have to take care of those `'` before and after a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can send parameter in method save, or what you use and use named SQL queries

```
  Query persistableQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO TASK_ASSESSMENT (ACTIVE_FLAG, ASSESSMENT_DATE, DESCRIPTION, TITLE, NEEDS_LEVEL_ID, PATIENT_ID, USER_ID) VALUES (":active_flag",":timeStampDate", ":description", ":title", ":needsLevelId", ":patientId", ":userId" )").setParameter("active_flag", your_object.getactive_flag).setParametr and etc

persistableQuery.executeUpdate();
```

but somewhere create object with all this fields.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - could you try reformat it so it is easier to read?

Answer (score 0):

In hibernate 5.3 and above positional parameters are deprecated so we need to use keys for parameter. Hql does not support insert with parameter. We need to follow below approch

```
import org.hibernate.query.Query;


    public void insertData() {

        String sql = "insert into employee(id,name,age,salary) values(:0,:1,:2,:3)";

        List<Object>  paramList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        paramList.add(1);    // id
        paramList.add("sumit"); // name
        paramList.add("23");  // age
        paramList.add(10000);  // salary

        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = getSessionfactory().openSession();

            Query query= session.createNativeQuery(sql);

            for(int i=0;i<paramList.size();i++) {
                query.setParameter(""+i,paramList.get(i));   // remember to add "" before i , we need to maintain key value pair in setParameter()
            }
            query.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
```